# Vagrant up wit puppet => install compass

Tags: ruby, centos, vagrant, puppet, compass-sass

Is there anybody who has experience with installing compass via puppet on a vagrant box?

If I'm installing compass via the following puppet command (http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/installing-ruby-gems-in-puppet/):

```
package { ['sass', 'compass']:
    ensure => 'installed',
    provider => 'gem',
}
```

The sass package is installed in a few seconds. The compass package is also installed but it takes about 30 minutes to install. And that's a bit anoying if you want to destroy and up the box on a regular base.

I use this VagrantBox => puppetlabs/centos-7.2-64-puppet

I also installed the following needed centos packages:

"rubygems", "ruby-devel"

Is there anybody with a solution?

Thx!

Comment: If I'm running it with debug = on, the script halts on the following command: `/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri compass`

Comment: compass has quite a lot of dependency but man, 30 minutes. another possibility for you would be to build your box once and repackage as a new box so if you destroy you will (re)up from the repackaged box

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution. If I tried the same scenario on my localhost it succeeded in 1 minute. I compared the gem version and the gem version on the puppet was an older version.

Now I'm first executing:

```
/bin/gem update --system
```